# SAP UI5 - passing user data to back end to perform select

Tags: sql, input, filter, odata, sapui5

First of all I'm pretty new to UI5..I'm developing in Eclipse.

I'm building an App where the user can search for flights. So he has a simple form with textfields like "Carrid", "Fldate", and so on.
After pressing a button he will navigate to the second view, where the relevant data is listed in a table.

I created an OData Service to get the data from the table in the backend. It works but I think it could be pretty unefficient because I select all data from the table in getEntitySet Method of the OData Service.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM SFLIGHTS
  INTO TABLE et_entityset.
```

But I want to achieve something similar like that:

```
  SELECT * FROM sflights INTO TABLE lt_sflights
  WHERE connid    IN ls_seloptions-connid    AND
        carrid    IN ls_seloptions-carrid    AND
        fldate    IN ls_seloptions-fldate    AND
        countryfr IN ls_seloptions-countryfr AND
        countryto IN ls_seloptions-countryto AND
        cityfrom  IN ls_seloptions-cityfrom  AND
        cityto    IN ls_seloptions-cityto.
```

So basically I need to pass the data from the input fields to the back-end system to perform the select this way.

I could theoretically filter the OData-entityset with the user input by applying a filter to the model like that

```
    var oFilters = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Carrid", "EQ", "AA")];
    oTable.bindRows("/SFLIGHTSSet", oFilters);
```

but I think it's pretty unefficient when tables with lots of entries are send through odata services? Therefore I think it would be better to send the user data to back-end and select in the back-end the correct entries, sending them back via OData.

I hope you understand my question and can help me!

Comment: Implement a filter in your OData service: $filter=CarrId eq "whatever". Then your frontend can pass the params of interest to the backend via this filter. Your backend can use those filters in the SQL request and send back the returned data. Is this clear?

Comment: Ah thank you! 
I just missed the option of filtering the odata services. Now I have it, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Chris Neve, I know how to use $filter in odata service, but I want to filter directly in backend instead of filtering odata. The filter in backend depends of IDUser or user's roles. Can you help me, please? Thanks.